# Is the difference between $ 2$ coprimes always either 1 or prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If a and b are both positive and coprime with $a > b$, Is $a - b$ always either $1$ or prime number?  Can $a - b$ be composite number?

Comment: $9-5=4$ (fill characters)

Comment: Absolutely not.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are many examples, and here is how to construct as many as you want (so you don't have to go looking for them): Find two positive, coprime integers $m, n$ such that $n$ is composite. Then $a = m+n$ and $b = m$ are coprime, but their difference $n$ is composite.

Comment: +1: It is sufficient that $b$ is composite; $a$ may be prime.

Comment: @CameronBuie I didn't claim to have found _all_ examples, but I did the edit anyway.

Comment: Sorry.  There is one additional restriction in my question:  a and b are both positive, coprime and composite, a > b, is a - b either 1 or prime?

Comment: @T.C. Directly constructing cases where $a$ and $b$ are both composite as well is a lot more tricky, and dives deep down into the structure of the primes (it seems to go down the same road as the Goldbach conjecture, for instance, and is far beyond me). However, there are loads of examples, like $a = 64, b = 49$ gives $a-b = 15$.

Comment: I forgot an additional restriction to my question:  If a and b are both positive, composite and coprime, is a - b always 1 or prime number?

Comment: @Arthur.  Ok.  That answers my question then.  Thanks lots.

Comment: @T.C. Also, look for primitive pythagorean triples for a lot of examples where $a, b$ and $a - b$ are not only composites, but also squares, like $25-9 = 16$ and $169-25 = 144$.